# regular expressions: what's the best option for matching urls with several or expressions

Tags: c#, regex, performance, regex-lookarounds, .net-8.0

suppose you're trying to match an urls which are compatible with the following 2 rules:

1. ends with the word .../contactos(/)
2. or has the word .../gestao/... in the middle of the url

Initially, I've started with the following pattern (pattern 1):

```
^(?:(?:/.+)+/contactos/?(?!.))|(?:(?:/.*)+/gestao(?:/.+))$
```

It works, but the negative lookahead which is required in this case seemed out of place, so I've replaced with the following pattern (lets call it pattern 2):

```
^(?:(?:/.+)+/contactos/?)$|^(?:(?:/.*)+/gestao(?:/.+))$
```

The main difference is that I'm using begin/end anchors to delimit each expression instead of having a single pair like in the first example (I'm not capturing groups in both cases, so that's really the only difference between both patterns). By "isolating" each "option", I can discard the negative lookahead used on pattern 1.

Since pattern 2 doesn't use lookaheads, I expected that it should be faster than pattern 1. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. I've built a small benchmark with .net 8 and it seems like pattern 1 is slightly faster than pattern for matching urls. Here's the code I've written (not really an experienced Benchmark user, so maybe I'm missing something):

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class RegexPerformance {
    
    private const string _patternNoCapture = "^(?:(?:/.+)+/contactos/?(?!.))|(?:(?:/.*)+/gestao(?:/.+))$";
    private const string _patternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors = "^(?:(?:/.+)+/contactos/?)$|^(?:(?:/.*)+/gestao(?:/.+))$";

    private Regex _noCapture = default!;

    private Regex _noCaptureWithStart = default!;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup() {
        _noCapture = new (_patternNoCapture,
                               RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        
        _noCaptureWithStart = new (_patternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors,
                                        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<string> Urls => [
        "/test/contactos",
        "/test/contactos/",
        "/test/someplace/gestao/123/yyy",
        "/test/someplace/gestao/123"
    ];
    
    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Urls))]
    public bool MatchPatternNoCapture(string url) => _noCapture.IsMatch(url);
    
    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Urls))]
    public bool MatchPatternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors(string url) => _noCaptureWithStart.IsMatch(url);


}
```

And here are the results:

```
| Method                                   | url                  | Mean       | Error     | StdDev    | Median     | Allocated |
|----------------------------------------- |--------------------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|-----------:|----------:|
| MatchPatternNoCapture                    | /test/contactos      |   244.5 ns |   8.25 ns |  23.53 ns |   238.6 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors | /test/contactos      |   224.3 ns |   3.14 ns |   2.62 ns |   223.5 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCapture                    | /test/contactos/     |   256.6 ns |   5.67 ns |  15.80 ns |   259.9 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors | /test/contactos/     |   278.6 ns |  18.98 ns |  53.84 ns |   260.6 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCapture                    | /test(...)o/123 [26] | 1,081.5 ns |  37.01 ns | 104.39 ns | 1,057.7 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors | /test(...)o/123 [26] | 1,367.4 ns | 167.26 ns | 493.18 ns | 1,121.6 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCapture                    | /test(...)3/yyy [30] | 1,861.4 ns |  73.08 ns | 201.28 ns | 1,789.4 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors | /test(...)3/yyy [30] | 1,925.6 ns |  58.13 ns | 168.65 ns | 1,919.0 ns |         - |
```

Btw, I've run another simple test with a non-matching url (`/test/contactosbad`)and in this case it seems like pattern 2 behaves slghtly better than pattern 1:

```
| Method                                   | url                | Mean     | Error    | StdDev   | Allocated |
|----------------------------------------- |------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|
| MatchPatternNoCapture                    | /test/contactosbad | 668.4 ns | 13.44 ns | 14.38 ns |         - |
| MatchPatternNoCaptureWithStartEndAnchors | /test/contactosbad | 518.2 ns | 10.30 ns | 14.43 ns |         - |
```

I must admit that I'm a little puzzled with these results. I expected pattern 2 to behave much better than pattern 1, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas on why this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your patterns are good: they are prone to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Namely, the quantified groups with all-mighty dots: `(?:/.+)+` and `(?:/.*)+`. These will take a long time to run on inputs which are just a bit longer. Here's an 115-characters input suggested by [a ReDoS checker](https://devina.io/redos-checker):

```
/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao/stao
```

This triggered a timeout [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RvbWtv/1) after about 10 seconds (it might be a bit faster on your machine, since regex101 seems to be running the regex on client side). To put it in perspective, the time complexity of such a group is `O(2^n)` (exponential).

Instead, keep it simple:

```
^
(?:
  /.+/contactos/?$
|
  /.+/gestao/.+
)
```

The first `.+` runs till the end in 1 step, then backtracks until it finds the fixed `/contactos` (*n* steps); the second `.+` does the same (*n* steps). The third do not need to backtrack, so it also takes only 1 step; you can replace it with a single `.` if you just want a boolean and not a full match. Collectively, the time complexity of this pattern is `O(n)` (linear).

I haven't run a benchmark yet (consulting ChatGPT on how to write a proper C# program) but I expect this to outperform your patterns both in performance and readability. As an example, regex101 [reports no match](https://regex101.com/r/RvbWtv/2) for an input of ten times longer than the input above in just *milliseconds*.

#### Addendum

The pattern above can also be written as:

```
^/.+/(?:contactos/?$|gestao/.+)
```

The engine will only try out the branches whenever `.+` backtracks to a `/`. This, therefore, will take less steps, but still `O(n)`.